# Changing the column order of a content type not working as expected

Tags: content-type, form, site-column

I'm having a silly problem that I can't get rid of: I have defined a content type based on the task content type. I've just added a couple of basic columns and removed others. When I reorder the column order of the content type it changes the order the fields appear in the edit item form. But here's my problem: two of the columns keep showing up on the very bottom of the form no matter what I do or where I try to place them. All the other fields show up in the order I chose.

Has anyone else seen this? It sure looks like a bug, doesn't it?

/Sebastian

EDIT: The order of the columns in the top level site content type is as I want it to be but even though I have "Update all content types inheriting from this type" checked the changes I do don't get promoted to the same content type on the sub sites. Maybe they are not even supposed to? Are the content types on every sub site considered as unique content types?

Comment: Which two columns?

Comment: Due date and task status.

Answer (score 2):

I would be interested to see if these two columns are actually part of the content type you created.  As an example, could they by part of the Item Content type that is default when you enable content types on a List.  It does sound like these columns are "out in Left field"  When you click on the Content Type to actual set the order and maintain the ctype?  I suspect that the columns that you are talking about might just be list columns and not associated with the ctype in question.

Comment: That was not the case, but it still lead me to the right place. The order of the site column is as I want it to be but even though I have "Update all content types inheriting from this type" checked the changes I do don't get promoted to the sub sites. Maybe they are not even supposed to?